# Program wont connect through OpenVPN

Tags: networking, macos, vpn, openvpn, sql-server

I have a MAC M1 that needs to run a windows native app (no MAC option of such app) and to do so I installed a Windows 11 arm x64 with VmWare Fusion - the app that runs needs to connect to SQL on my work network

I set up the OpenVPN, Windows connected perfectly from the Windows VM to the network and I can ping everything on the network, even the SQL server that the app uses,

However, when I try to use the app it fails stating that the SQL-server is not connecting.

Ports to the SQL are being forwarded. Also, I'm using UDMP as the OpenVPN server.

Maybe there is something to redirect from and to the mac host connection for the windows to reach outside with its OpenVPN?

I'm really lost on this one.

Maybe the app is not using the OpenVPN connection at all?

Both firewalls, MAC and Windows are down while I test, so no issue there.

TELNET does connects to sql.